# How can I make a download link usable for only one person

Tags: wordpress

I am making a site with Wordpress and I want to know how I can make a file or more specifically a download link only usable by a single user. ie. if anyone other than that person tries to use the link they would get an error.

I use *Advanced Access Manager* for restricting users from different parts of the site and my theme is *impreza* and for login form *user pro*.

Answer (score 0):

I'd really recommend for this you use the EDD plugin: https://easydigitaldownloads.com/

It's well supported and documented and does what you require.

Comment: second i did not want that my user need to buy file for using it the WordPress Download Manager did what i want.